# Updating a list according to another list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have lists `J` and `CB`. I am updating `J` based on elements in `CB` but I want to insert `0` whenever `CB[i]=[]`. I present the current and expected outputs.

```
import numpy as np

J=[[1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10]]

CB=[[],
 [np.array([0.00351331]), np.array([0.0070412]), np.array([0.00352908])],
 [],
 [np.array([0.01067821])],
 [np.array([0.01070989])],
 [np.array([0.01067821])],
 [np.array([0.01070989])]]

J = [J[0][i] for i, a in enumerate(CB) if np.array(a).size != 0]
print(J)
```

The current output is

```
[2, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

The expected output is

```
[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a conditional in your list comprehension, not a filter:

```
J = [J[0][i] if np.array(a).size != 0 else 0 for i, a in enumerate(CB)]
print(J)
```

Output: `[0, 2, 0, 6, 7, 9, 10]`

Answer (score 0):

```
J = [j if a else 0
     for j, a in zip(J[0], CB)]
```